# Gnome 17.04. shows half of the networks that are available on my Windows/Mac machine

Tags: networking

Title says it all.

I freshly installed GNOME 17.04 on my old laptop (Lenovo G550) and everything was going smoothly but when I was about to connect to the network I couldn't see my 2 networks (2.4 and 5.0).

How can I solve this problem?

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your two networks aren't silent/hidden are they?   hidden or silent networks aren't shown until you've connected once (the same as as windows & mac)

Comment: No they're not. It's just your typical stock WPA2 networks. Thanks for reminding me tho. I also tried to write the name of both networks as if they were hidden, still nothing